# What's the best way to set up kiosk mode for XP?

Tags: windows-xp, kiosk

Is it possible to lock down and XP machine for kiosk only for non-admins?  How?  At the moment I need Internet only?  Also, is it possible to run Kiosk more for more than just Internet, maybe one or two other applications?  Thank you.

edit:  what about using group policy?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**Windows SteadyState**](http://www.intelliadmin.com/blog/2007/11/free-kiosk-utility-for-windows.html) and [**Opera kiosk mode**](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/). You can lock down as much as possible with group policy then install SteadyState. If someone manages to get by all the policies and out of kiosk mode from Opera, simply reboot the machine to restore everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make commercial "kiosk" product(s), you may want to consider [Windows XP Embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/default.aspx).