# How can I lockdown a computer so the user cannot minimize or move the browser window?

Tags: windows, browser, kiosk, security-policy

I am trying to setup a computer with a browser page. The webpage allows people to enter their email address and submit a form.

However, it is intended to be a kiosk. I don't want people to be able to minimize or move or drag around or visit any other URL.

How can I lock things down? Can I configure local security policy somehow? I am planning on using a Windows XP, or Windows 7.

Thank you,

Comment: For XP: [What's the best way to set up kiosk mode for XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/48012/whats-the-best-way-to-set-up-kiosk-mode-for-xp)

Answer (score 0):

here are plenty of kiosk software available to do this, I have used and can recommend SiteKiosk although I can't say if it is better or worse than others.

Many of the different vendors offer Free Trials, so check a few out

There also is OpenKiosk, an Open Source alternative.

Another real good choice appears to Webconverger which claims to be a Browser Only Operating System. In practice it appears to be a micro-linux, and I am not sure what customization is available.

googled lock down kiosk windows 7 and found these softwares. Seems legit and pretty solid.

Internet Kiosk Pro (http://www.emailarms.com/products/internet_kiosk.html)

Advanced Internet Kiosk (http://www.softstack.com/advink.html)

Secure Lockdown (http://shop.inteset.com/Products/21-lock-down-windows-7-and-run-internet-explorer-as-a-customized-kiosk-application.aspx)

Sitekiosk (http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx)

Or as Dark mentioned in the comments, there is a built in Kiosk mode into WIndows 8.1. If you can put this project on hold until the official release, this may give you the functionality that you're wanting without having to purchase third-party software.

Take a look at [Windows SteadyState](http://www.intelliadmin.com/blog/2007/11/free-kiosk-utility-for-windows.html) and [Opera kiosk mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/). You can lock down as much as possible with group policy then install SteadyState. If someone manages to get by all the policies and out of kiosk mode from Opera, simply reboot the machine to restore everything.